# Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed at [18:10]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
WITH lep_find As ( 
  SELECT date, 
         admin_level_1, 
         tests_total, 
         tests_increase 
  FROM bigquery-405008.about_covid_19_public_datasets.summary 
           LIMIT 1000 ), 
Total as ( 
  SELECT lep_find.tests_total, 
         lep_find.tests_increase, 
         Sum (lep_find.tests_total + lep_find.tests_increase) AS total_count 
  FROM lep_find ) 
Select * from Total;
```

I have written the code and I want to show all the Raw with Existing/New Column in the database

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question. In Lep_find, why have you got a GROUP BY when you aren’t aggregating anything? Why have you got the total CTE when you don’t use it?

Comment: I edited my code still not working, I don't know where am I wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? Is it erroring - in which case, what is the error message? Is it not giving the result you expect - in which case what result is it giving and what did you expect? Also, don't you want to have a GROUP BY in the Total CTE?